# automate the following steps

Tags: batch-file, putty, plink

I have created an .bat file with the following command with a text file which contain "sudo su - oradev2"(C.txt).

---

cd C:\Users\chakraborty_sayantan\Desktop
plink -ssh serverA -l username -pw password -m "C:\Users\username\Desktop\c.txt" -t

---

The command above completes the first step of logging into a DB and the c.txt file has the instruction to enter into sudo mode. However, post this there is an authentication. Is there a way to automate the step of entering the password? Any thoughts?
Procedure to automate

1. login
2. password
3. sudo su - oradev
4. password
5. echo $ORACLE_SID
6. sqlplus / as sysdba
7. create user  identified by
8. default tablspace
   The above steps need to get automate using a bat file which consist of plink/putty.

[image]

-Sayantan

Comment: Normally you should use ssh with private/public keys instead of passwords

Comment: can you help me out by rewriting the code..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a password and username txt file and maybe use the `IF NOT EXIST` Command to check if that user and pass file exists and set some commands up to create that file

Hope this is what you meant :)

Comment: if you have seen the pic in that i am able to get into the sudo but i need to enter the password. is there a way that the password be stored in a variable and pass when the prompt ask me the password. Basically, all that I am trying to do is 1) login to a server 2) type sudo su - db_instance 3) enter sudo password. I am able to automate step 1 and 2 and got stuck at 3 while passing the password using a batch file

Comment: @SAYANTANChakraborty Im gonna guess youre talking about using ftp so you may want to ask about that, im not an expert on ftp sadly so I cant help when it comes to servers

Comment: OK #yoshirou i can understand .. and thanks for your suggestion.